# What is meant by "OS resolver libraries" that are used by the "dig" command?

Tags: linux, command-line, dig, nslookup, host-name-resolution

I know that `dig` queries the DNS server in the `/etc/resolv.conf`
but I read that the difference between `dig` and `nslookup` is that `dig` uses OS resolver libraries.
But what are the OS resolver libraries?

Answer (score 2):

OS resolver libraries are functions (mainly `gethostbyname()` and `gethostbyaddr()`) which are part of the C library and which allow to resolve hostnames to IP addresses.  To do so, they use the configuration file `/etc/nsswitch.conf` to decide whether they must resort to DNS, NIS, or to a simple hosts lookup file.

On the other hand, `nslookup` uses its own internal resolver. For some time this command used to be deprecated.

Related question: [dig vs nslookup](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/93808/dig-vs-nslookup)